# Regex for two consecutive zero's at start of input

Tags: regex

I need to write regex expression which can disallow inputs to have two consecutive zeros at the start of input

i've following regex rightnow
 /[^0-9]+/g 
there is one issue with this, as it allows as many zeros at the start of input which is wrong, ideally i would like something which can allow one zero at start if user enters zero first followed by any numbers but no more zero at start so valid input should be 0,1, 01,099,100,10000000 , 980980567000 etc
invalid input 00,001,00100,00100000 , 000087990432 etc

Comment: Do you want your regex to match valid or invalid inputs?

Comment: Also, the question as written doesn't seem related to angularjs. Please remove that tag.

Answer (score 5):

Matches invalid inputs: `/^00\d*/`

Matches valid inputs: `/^(?!00)\d/*`

`^` stands for the beginning of the string 
`00` matches two consecutives zeros 
`(?!00)` is a negative lookahead for two consecutive zeros 
`\d*` matches any sequence of numbers

Comment: i'm sorry if i was not clear but i'm trying to write regex expression which if find invalid character then replace that invalid character with  empty string ('').In my case the characters should be valid if they are only positive numbers and they dont start with two or more zeros.
var pattern = /^[0]{0,1}[1-9]\d{0,}/;  var parsed = val.replace(pattern, '');
Note: val is an input like abcdgj, 0010000, 0001111198 etc etc
But using above mentioned expression it allows to enter any other  characters as well like alphabets, special characters, negative numbers etc which is wrong in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

To match any static string at the beginning of a string (including "00"), you can use the `^` anchor.

To match strings starting with "00", your regex would be `/^00/`. If you want specifically numeric strings, `/^00[0-9]*/`.

Comment: i'm sorry if i was not clear but i'm trying to write regex expression which if find invalid character then replace that invalid character with  empty string ('').

in my case the characters should be valid if they are only positive numbers and they dont start with two or more zeros.
var pattern = /^00[0-9]*/;
var parsed = val.replace(pattern, '');

Note: val is an input like abcdgj, 0010000, 0001111198 etc etc

But using your expression it allows to enter any other characters as well like alphabets, special characters, negative numbers etc etc which is wrong in my scenario

Comment: If your question is about replacing parts strings, can you please update it to state exactly what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Regexp matchers are good at saying what has to be matched, but it's a little trickie to tell a matcher what has not to be matched.  To unmatch all strings beginning with `00` you have to match all strings that begin with different than `0` and all strings that, beginning with `0` don't continue with a `0` (being the empty string valid, as the string `0` doesn't begin with `00`), so one such right expression could be:

```
^[^0].*$|^0([^0].*)?$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/paZWwg/1) for details.