# Replace leading digits in a string if consists of optional zeros then 2 specific numbers

Tags: php, regex, phone-number, sanitization, leading-zero

I get a phone number, where I would like to replace

```
0049
049
49
```

with a null.

I can do it like this:

```
$phone = str_replace("0049", "0", $phone);
// and so on
```

But for the case that a "049" is in the middle of the phone number:

```
00491384004924
```

Fail!! :/

How can I do it better?

Comment: _"replace ... with a null"_... what does this mean exactly? Could you please [edit] your question to show some examples of the results you want?

Comment: Topical: [Regex for two consecutive zero's at start of input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41795718/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does the phone got fixed length (like mobile number) ?
if so , then check length of phone number and remove first symbols based on the lenght.
something like this

```
$phone = "00491384004924";
if(strlen($phone) > 10) {
    $removeFirst = strlen($phone) - 10 ; 
    $phone = substr($phone, $removeFirst); // remove the first 4 symbols
    echo $phone = "0".$phone;
}
```

and result is

```
01384004924
```

Comment: it can be a mobile number but also a "normal" number. both with different lengths

Comment: all numbers have fixed length no matter what they are, if you want to check for both, just add another if with the length of the normal number

Answer (score 3):

Use [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/function.preg-replace.php) with a [start-of-string anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

```php
$phone = preg_replace('/^0{0,2}49/', '0', $phone);
```

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/YRkeB

```
/
 ^      - start of line anchor
 0{0,2} - literal "0" repeated 0 to 2 times
 49     - literal "49"
/
```

Comment: Shouldn't the replacement string be an empty string, Phil?

Comment: I just went with OP's code as an example of what they _actually_ wanted. They never got back to me when [I asked for clarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74092887/replace-leading-digits-in-a-string-if-consists-of-optional-zeros-then-2-specific/74093068?noredirect=1#comment130818764_74092887)